"RegisterSecureMemoryCacheCallback" exception in C program
Could someone please explain this error?  It craps out when I try to free the array.  It works fine when I malloc inside of main so I'm guessing its because of the function scope?  I thought if I return the pointer to the malloc then it wouldn't matter where I try to free it.
Thread 1 received signal SIGTRAP, Trace/breakpoint trap.
0x00007ffd80a5719f in ntdll!RtlRegisterSecureMemoryCacheCallback () from C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct array { int length; int size; void *data; } array;

static array* new(int length, int size)
{
    array *array = malloc(sizeof(array));
    array->length = length;
    array->size = size;
    array->data = malloc(length * size);
    return array;
}

int main()
{
    array *a = new(5, sizeof(int));

    free(a->data);
    free(a); // debugger points me to here

    return 0;
}


Bonus points for having a structure tag, a type name, and a variable name, all with the same name. What does sizeof(array) take the size of? The structure or the pointer?

@pmacfarlane - lol, due to your comment I tried changing the name of array to _array and it works now?  Is "array" a keyword or something?

No, it's just getting the size of the wrong thing. You wanted the size of the structure, but you got the size of the variable instead.

No, it's not a keyword. But you have both a type and a variable with the same name. I don't know the exact rule which states which one sizeof() would prefer, but this is just confusing. Don't do it.

It's not too bad using the same name for the struct and typedef (C++ does this automatically), although it's a common convention to use _t in typedef names, e.g. typedef struct foo { ...} foo_t;

If you're going to typedef the struct anyway, no point giving it a tag at all. In fact MISRA will complain for a tagged struct where the tag is never used (since everything uses the typedefr).

@pmacfarlane - oh ok, I didn't know you could do that LOL, learning so much today

Interestingly, code like int int; fails to compile, but typedef int foo; foo foo; does compile. Maybe a language lawyer can make a good answer to this question.

@pmacfarlane int is a keyword.  You can't use it as a variable name or a type name.

_changing the name of array to array and it works now Be cautious using a leading underscore for your own names.
